# How to find $y'$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ for the curve $5x^{2} - xy - 4y^{2} = 0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find $y'$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ for $5x^{2} - xy - 4y^{2} = 0$.

Quite confused about how I'd go about this, the solution will be helpful (I'm good at working backwards) but an explanation will be appreciated if anyone has the time.

Comment: You can do this using implicit differentiation. If you haven't learned implicit differentiation yet, I'd be very surprised that your teacher gave you this homework. But anyway, it's closely related to the chain rule

Comment: Hint: remember that $y=y(x)$ and apply the chain rule, deriving both sides of the equation.

Comment: Differentiate the left hand side w.r.t. $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$5x^{2} - xy - 4y^{2} = 0$
Diff w.r.t x on both sides

$5(2x) - (xy' + y(1)) - 4(2y)y' = 0 $

$10x - xy' -y -8yy' = 0$

Rearranging

$y' = \frac{10x - y}{x + 8y}$

Answer (score 0):

use the implicit function theorem
$5x^2-xy-4y^2=0\Rightarrow 10x-y-x\frac{dy}{dx}-8y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ and solve $\frac{dy}{dx}$, that is to say:
\begin{equation}
y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{10x-y}{x+8y}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that $y$ is just a shorthand for $y(x)$, we can write the equation as
$$
5x^2-xy(x)-4y(x)^2=0 \, ,
$$
and so
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(5x^2-xy(x)-4y(x)^2\right)&=\frac{d}{dx}(0) \\
10x-y(x)-xy'(x)-8y(x)y'(x) &= 0 \, ,
\end{align}
using the chain and product rules. Rearranging this equation should leave you with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick... differentiate with respect to x, treating y as a constant.  Put it all in brackets and write "dx" at the end.  Then do the same thing over again except you will be differentiating with respect to y and and treating x as a constant.

$\frac {\partial}{\partial x}(5x^2 - xy - 4y^2)\ dx + \frac {\partial}{\partial y}(5x^2 - xy - 4y^2)\ dy = 0\\
(10x - y) \ dx + (-x - 8y)\ dy = 0$

Now solve for $\frac {dy}{dx}$

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {10 - y}{x+8y}$